# is there any way to pass comma separated string as a single argument while creating new process

Tags: c#, batch-processing

"I'am creating process as i want to pass comma separated string as single argument but it is considering only one argument."

```
var process = new Process{
    StartInfo = { 
                 Arguments = string.Format("{0},{1},2}",
                 item,
                 storagePath + item,
  "_id,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k") 
    },
};
```

"Process should be created with "item" as 1st, "storagePath + item" as 2nd argument and "_id,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k" as third argument."

Comment: That should work if you add literal quotes around the data, i.e. "\"bla, bla, bla\"".

Comment: Thanks,  it works fine. but, if i want use Field instead of string how can i use it? where, Field is, public const string Field = "_id,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k";

Comment: You just need to make sure your argument string has double quotes on both ends.

Comment: it is having double quotes but still it is taking only one argument i.e. 1st one _id

Comment: thank you for your support, it works for me i initialized Field as follows, public const string Field = "\"_id,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k\""